# Sending Form using Wordpress and jQuery doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple script for a form submit using javascript / jQuery. For some reason, it works the first time (for 10 days) now I got this error in firefox (console):

POST https://mydomain.de/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Status 403 Forbidden

Version HTTP/1.1

Übertragen 567 B (2 B Größe)

Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Code in functions.php

```
// e-Mail handling
// if you want only logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_before_submit', 'mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit');

// if you want none logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_before_submit', 'mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit');

// if you want both logged in and anonymous users to get the emails, use both hooks above

function mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit(){
check_ajax_referer('my_email_ajax_nonce');
if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "mail_before_submit" ){

            // catch vars for mail
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $anschrift = $_POST['anschrift'];
            $telefon = $_POST['tel'];
            $wohnort = $_POST['wohnort'];
            $klasse = $_POST['klasse'];
            $customer_mail = $_POST['toemail'];
            $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];

            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: Fahrschule Website <info@fahrschule.com>');

            $msg_body = '<h3>Anmeldung von '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' - '.$klasse.'</h3>';
            $msg_body.= '<p>Der Fahrschüler meldet sich mit folgenden Daten an:<br><br>';
            $msg_body.= $firstname.' '.$lastname.'<br>'.$anschrift.'<br>'.$wohnort.'<br><br>Geburtsdatum und -ort: '.$birthdate.'<br><br>Telefon: '.$telefon.'<br>E-Mail: '.$customer_mail;
            $msg_body.= '</p>';


        //send email  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ex:
    wp_mail('info@xyz.de','Anmeldung Fahrerlaubnis',$msg_body, $headers);
    echo 'Anmeldung gesendet';
    wp_die();
}
echo 'Fehler beim senden';
die();
}
```

Code from js-file

```
function send_form() {

jQuery('.alert-info').hide();
//jQuery('.alert-info').fadeIn();
var myModal = document.getElementById('modalRegister');
var err_firstname = document.getElementById('err_firstname');
//jQuery('#err_firstname').hide();
var auswahl = jQuery('#test-auswahl').val();
var klasse = optionRequired('test-auswahl', 'Klasse');
var fn = checkEmpty('firstname', 'Vorname');
var ln = checkEmpty('lastname', 'Nachname');
var an = checkEmpty('anschrift', 'Straße / Nr');
var an = checkEmpty('plz_ort', 'Plz / Wohnort');
var tel = checkEmpty('tel', 'Telefon');
var tel = checkEmpty('geb_dat', 'Geburtsdatum / Ort');
var mailf = validateEmail('email', "E-Mail Adresse");

if(fn && ln && an && tel && mailf && klasse) {
    jQuery('.alert-info').html('Formular gesendet! Anmeldung für ' + auswahl);
    jQuery('.alert-info').fadeIn();
    jQuery('.inhalt').hide();
    jQuery('.modal-footer .btn-primary').hide();

    // Mail testen
    var data = {
        action: 'mail_before_submit',
        toemail: jQuery('#fbfrm_email').val(), // change this to the email field on your form
            lastname: jQuery('#fbfrm_lastname').val(),
            firstname: jQuery('#fbfrm_firstname').val(),
            anschrift: jQuery('#fbfrm_anschrift').val(),
            wohnort: jQuery('#fbfrm_plz_ort').val(),
            tel: jQuery('#fbfrm_tel').val(),
            klasse: jQuery('#test-auswahl').val(),
        _ajax_nonce: jQuery('#my_email_ajax_nonce').data('nonce'),
    };
    jQuery.post(window.location.origin + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
        console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Is your website hosted with GoDaddy?

Comment: no, it‘s a virtual server self managed. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: `check_ajax_referer` probably kills your request here. With the default true for the third parameter, it will output `-1` on failure, and that would match the 2 Bytes of actual content length you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much - it works :) I'd changed it to: `check_ajax_referer('my_email_ajax_nonce', false, false);`